# Code-formatting error

Tags: support, code-formatting

I've looked at many answers on this topic but none of these solutions seem to work in my case. The error I get:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
>   code.

Made sure there is space after headings, no semicolons in the list, etc. I am trying to answer a question with this:

```
Since there are big differences between the input images, the algorithm should be able to adapt to the situation. Since Canny is based on detecting high frequencies, my algorithm treats the sharpness of the image as the parameter used for preprocessing adaptation. I didn't want to spend a week figuring out the functions for all the data, so I applied a simple, linear function based on 2 images and then tested with a third one. Here are my results.


[![first result][1]][1]
[![second result][2]][2]
[![third result][3]][3]


Have in mind that this is a very basic approach and is only proving a point. It will need experiments, tests, and refining. The idea is to use Sobel and sum over all the pixels acquired. That, divided by the size of the image, should give you a basic estimation of high freq. response of the image. Now, experimentally, I found values of clipLimit for CLAHE filter that work in 2 test cases and found a **[linear function][4]** connecting the high freq. response of the input with a CLAHE filter, yielding good results.


    sobel = get_sobel(img)
    clip_limit = (-2.556) * np.sum(sobel)/(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]) + 26.557


That's the adaptive part. Now for the contours. It took me a while to figure out a correct way of filtering out the noise. I settled for a simple trick: using contours finding twice. First I use it to filter out the unnecessary, noisy contours. Then I continue with some morphological magic to end up with correct blobs for the objects being detected (more details in the code). The final step is to filter bounding rectangles based on the calculated mean, since, on all of the samples, the blobs are of relatively similar size.



    import cv2
    import numpy as np


    def unsharp_mask(img, blur_size = (5,5), imgWeight = 1.5, gaussianWeight = -0.5):
        gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5,5), 0)
        return cv2.addWeighted(img, imgWeight, gaussian, gaussianWeight, 0)


    def smoother_edges(img, first_blur_size, second_blur_size = (5,5), imgWeight = 1.5, gaussianWeight = -0.5):
        img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, first_blur_size, 0)
        return unsharp_mask(img, second_blur_size, imgWeight, gaussianWeight)


    def close_image(img, size = (5,5)):
        kernel = np.ones(size, np.uint8)
        return cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


    def open_image(img, size = (5,5)):
        kernel = np.ones(size, np.uint8)
        return cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)


    def shrink_rect(rect, scale = 0.8):
        center, (width, height), angle = rect
        width = width * scale
        height = height * scale
        rect = center, (width, height), angle
        return rect


    def clahe(img, clip_limit = 2.0):
        clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=clip_limit, tileGridSize=(5,5))
        return clahe.apply(img)


    def get_sobel(img, size = -1):
        sobelx64f = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,2,0,size)
        abs_sobel64f = np.absolute(sobelx64f)
        return np.uint8(abs_sobel64f)


    img = cv2.imread("blobs4.jpg")
    # save color copy for visualizing
    imgc = img.copy()
    # resize image to make the analytics easier (a form of filtering)
    resize_times = 5
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, img, fx = 1 / resize_times, fy = 1 / resize_times)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # use sobel operator to evaluate high frequencies
    sobel = get_sobel(img)
    # experimentally calculated function - needs refining
    clip_limit = (-2.556) * np.sum(sobel)/(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]) + 26.557

    # don't apply clahe if there is enough high freq to find blobs
    if(clip_limit < 1.0):
        clip_limit = 0.1
    # limit clahe if there's not enough details - needs more tests
    if(clip_limit > 8.0):
        clip_limit = 8

    # apply clahe and unsharp mask to improve high frequencies as much as possible
    img = clahe(img, clip_limit)
    img = unsharp_mask(img)

    # filter the image to ensure edge continuity and perform Canny
    # (values selected experimentally, using trackbars)
    img_blurred = (cv2.GaussianBlur(img.copy(), (2*2+1,2*2+1), 0))
    canny = cv2.Canny(img_blurred, 35, 95)

    # find first contours
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # prepare black image to draw contours
    canvas = np.ones(img.shape, np.uint8)
    for c in cnts:
        l = cv2.arcLength(c, False)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        aspect_ratio = float(w)/h

        # filter "bad" contours (values selected experimentally)
        if l > 500:
            continue
        if l < 20:
            continue
        if aspect_ratio < 0.2:
            continue
        if aspect_ratio > 5:
            continue
        if l > 150 and (aspect_ratio > 10 or aspect_ratio < 0.1):
            continue
        # draw all the other contours
        cv2.drawContours(canvas, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # perform closing and blurring, to close the gaps
    canvas = close_image(canvas, (7,7))
    img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(canvas, (8*2+1,8*2+1), 0)
    # smooth the edges a bit to make sure canny will find continuous edges
    img_blurred = smoother_edges(img_blurred, (9,9))
    kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
    # erode to make sure separate blobs are not touching each other
    eroded = cv2.erode(img_blurred, kernel)
    # perform necessary thresholding before Canny
    _, im_th = cv2.threshold(eroded, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    canny = cv2.Canny(im_th, 11, 33)

    # find contours again. this time mostly the right ones
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # calculate the mean area of the contours' bounding rectangles
    sum_area = 0
    rect_list = []
    for i,c in enumerate(cnts):
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        _, (width, height), _ = rect
        area = width*height
        sum_area += area
        rect_list.append(rect)
    mean_area = sum_area / len(cnts)

    # choose only rectangles that fulfill requirement:
    # area > mean_area*0.6
    for rect in rect_list:
        _, (width, height), _ = rect
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box * 5)
        area = width * height

        if(area > mean_area*0.6):
            # shrink the rectangles, since the shadows and reflections
            # make the resulting rectangle a bit bigger
            # the value was guessed - might need refinig
            rect = shrink_rect(rect, 0.8)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box * resize_times)
            cv2.drawContours(imgc, [box], 0, (0,255,0),1)

    # resize for visualizing purposes
    imgc = cv2.resize(imgc, None, imgc, fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)
    cv2.imshow("imgc", imgc)
    cv2.imwrite("result3.png", imgc)
    cv2.waitKey(0)



Overall I think that's a very interesting problem, a little bit too big to be answered here. The approach I presented is due to be treated as a road sign, not a complete solution. Tha basic idea being: 
 1. Adaptive preprocessing.
 2. Finding contours twice: for filtering and then for the actual classification.
 3. Filtering the blobs based on their mean size.

Thanks for the fun and good luck!


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA3Lv.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwl6U.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mmb3.png
  [4]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9.80%20*%20a%20%2B%20b%20%3D%201.5;%208.04%20*%20a%20%2B%20b%20%3D%206
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, it's the images:

```
[![first result][1]][1]
[![second result][2]][2]
[![third result][3]][3]
```

Put a newline between 'em, and the system won't think it's code:

```
[![first result][1]][1]

[![second result][2]][2]

[![third result][3]][3]
```